# add html element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i need help to add element on html using jquery, i'm new on this territory, i've tried several method and failed

here's the HTML

```
<div id="relatedpostspro_0_1" class="rpp rpp_isotope" style="width:auto;">
    <div class="rpp_container">
        <legend>Related Posts</legend>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want to add this small piece

```
<div class="stripe-line"></div>
```

so it will result to:

```
<div id="relatedpostspro_0_1" class="rpp rpp_isotope" style="width:auto;">
    <div class="rpp_container">
        <legend>Related Posts</legend>
        <div class="stripe-line"></div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

using these 2 jquery from first 2 answer

```
$('.rpp_container').append('<div class="stripe-line"></div>');
```

and

```
var line = $('<div />').addClass('stripe-line');
line.appendTo('.rpp_container');
```

resulting the line added at the bottom, not right after `<legend>Related Posts</legend>`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, post your jQuery code as well so we know why your methods didn’t work.

Comment: i want to add stripe lines, tried several times with css using pseudo element :after and unsuccessful because it has repeat property. can't put width: 100%; because it's not start at left: 0; using overflow: hidden; not helping. the only things work only adding new element. tried with search replace not working, i'm new on this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `after`

```
$('.rpp_container legend').after('<div class="stripe-line"></div>');
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: work like a charm! thanks a lot. this community cool. usually it takes me 5 hours just to get 5-10 lines code, next time i will ask here after 3 hours trying :D

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're  in need of [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) ("Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements."):

```
$('.rpp_container legend').after('<div class="stripe-line"></div>');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c44j2vtz/)**

Which produces:

```
<div id="relatedpostspro_0_1" class="rpp rpp_isotope" style="width:auto;">
    <div class="rpp_container">
        <legend>Related Posts</legend>
        <div class="stripe-line"></div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many different methods to find / modify DOM elememts, [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) has already been shown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rpp_container').append('<div class="stripe-line"></div>');
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euuhyfr4/11/)**

---

You can also use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) with [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rpp_container').find('legend').after('<div class="stripe-line"></div>')
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euuhyfr4/13/)**

---

**A few other helpful methods for traversing the DOM:**

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: hi.. it works just by using `after()`. sorry for my igonrance, why using `find()`? i often saw jquery code using that, my guess is that to avoid wrong element?

Comment: Over time, your HTML may become more complicated, using `find` will help make it easier to select the correct element, this method basically  allows us to search through the descendants of a set of elements in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.rpp_container').append('<div class="stripe-line"></div>');
```